# Auto wiring with qualifier annotation

Tags: spring

I am trying to auto wire my Circle class. I am using a qualifier in order for Spring to able to distinguish between the two Point class beans i have created a qualifier.

```
public class Circle{
   private Point center;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("circleRelated")
   public void setCenter(Point center) {
      this.center = center;
   }

   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
      System.out.println("Centre point is " + center.getX());
   }
}
```

The Point class is as follows

```
public class Point {
   private int x;
   public int getX() { return x; }

   public void setX(int x) { this.x = x;}
}
```

The beans.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="circle" class="com.example.Circle"/>

   <bean id="pointA" class="com.example.Point">
     <qualifier value="circleRelated" />
     <property name="x" value="0"/>
     <property name="y" value="0"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="pointB" class="com.example.Point">
     <property name="x" value="-20"/>
     <property name="y" value="0"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

My main class is

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AutowiredAnnotationApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

       Circle circle = (Circle) context.getBean("circle");
       circle.draw();
   }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB
```

Why is spring unable to autowire the bean with the given qualifier?

Comment: I haven't used <context:annotation-config/> on purpose

Answer (score 0):

The `@Qualifier` gets the bean id as value. So you have to use "pointA" or "pointB"

```
public class Circle{
   private Point center;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("pointA")
   public void setCenter(Point center) {
      this.center = center;
   }

   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
      System.out.println("Centre point is " + center.getX());
   }
}
```

In general if you skip the @Qualifier - you autowire by type. That means "search in the Spring context a bean of that type and throw an exception if none or more than one is found".

If you add the @Qualifier("someName") that means - "search in the Spring context a bean of that type and with that name and throw an exception if none is found"

**Edit:**
Take a look at [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/43632-using-qualifiers-to-choose-dependency-in-xml). I don't think that you need  tag at all.

If you wan't to inject some bean using `@Autowired` the `@Qualifier` needs the bean id as it's value. For example `@Qualifier("pointA")` will require a bean with id: `pointA`.

If you want to inject the bean using only xml you can use `ref`. You don't need Qualifier for that, only for autowireing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="circle" class="com.example.Circle">
        <property name="center" ref="pointA"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="pointA" class="com.example.Point">
     <qualifier value="circleRelated" />
     <property name="x" value="0"/>
     <property name="y" value="0"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="pointB" class="com.example.Point">
     <property name="x" value="-20"/>
     <property name="y" value="0"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**Edit 2:** 
See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers). I believe that the qualifier tag is taken into account only if you skip the bean id, otherwise the bean id is used.

Comment: Thanks. What do I change for it to work with the `<qualifier value=""/>` tag

Comment: you are correct that I dont need a qualifier tag here. But then what use case does it even have?

Comment: @PranavKapoor See Edit 2

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this line from your beans.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

For some reason, it is meddling with your otherwise correct configuration.